# Selenium WebDriver Python: Unable to switch to pop up

Tags: python, selenium, binding, webdriver, popupwindow

I am working on an application that works only in IE and has ActiveX Grid. When I click on a grid cell, a 'pop up' opens and the popup has title like this: `<title of the window>--Webpage Dialog`.

`window_handles` gives me only one handle before(that of the parent window) and after opening the pop up.  Parent window becomes unclickable until the popup is closed.
When I open the developer tools on the IE window after opening the pop up, it shows me the pop up contents. It has one iframe and the edit boxes that I am supposed to work on.

All of my attempts to reach the edit boxes inside the iframe of the popup have not worked.

i tried-

```
driver.switch to default content()

driver.switchtoiframe(popup)
```

Error:

> NoSuchFrameException

`alert=driver.switchtoalert()##` Doesn't throw any errors but I am lost on how to reach the edit boxes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the latest Selenium Python binding then use `driver.switch_to.frame`
Notice the `.` after `switch_to`. `switch_to_frame()` is deprecated in latest version. See the [doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=switch#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_alert)